# Transform matrix into column on google sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a number of matrixes such as:

[image: Input Matrix]

I would like to transform this data in such way, that it is resembled in one column, such as:

[image: Output Rows]

Here is the link to a **testsheet** with exactly this data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kn6yYL3dsTZ7IL5Z8a5j0itfwZK9TkRQsBCzXdCG2zo/edit#gid=0

What I have done so far: I know, that I can do this using "transpose" or "mtrans" (same thing). But unfortunately for this I will have to do it manually. I'm looking for just ONE formular to solve this problem, so I don't have to always do it manually for every row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(MONATLICH!R3:Y<>""; "♠"&MONTH(MONATLICH!B3:B)&"♦"&MONATLICH!B3:B&"♦"&
 MONATLICH!C3:C&"♦"&MONATLICH!R2:Y2&"♦"&MONATLICH!R3:Y&"♦"&MONATLICH!Z3:AG; ))
 ;;999^99));;999^99); "♠")); "♦"))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rUhsZWRIT4OSakD78q8ExaSNXejRfs5dbV00oSft8DI/edit#gid=824030233)

Comment: Thank you very much! I have mistakenly linked to the wrong sheet. Here is the correct one. Could you delete your screenshot, because of the full names?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kn6yYL3dsTZ7IL5Z8a5j0itfwZK9TkRQsBCzXdCG2zo/edit#gid=0

Comment: And a quick question: What are the hearts, spaids and so on for in your formula?

Comment: sure. picture censored. ♦♠ are unique symbols and their purpose is to act like separators for SPLIT formula